# Trade Reconciliation Using Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, database-reconciliation

I am looking to quickly reconcile large volumes of trade valuations using PowerShell.

Example:

```
File_1 - Trade_id = 123456, 789101      Valuation = 10, 20
File_2 - Trade_id = 123456, 789101      Valuation = 10, 30
```

My question is how do I show the differences of the Valuation by `Trade_id` in a text file?

I was thinking something like this -

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content H:\File_1.txt) $(Get-Content H:\File_2.txt) | Out-File H:\datarecon.txt
```

However, the formatting of the results is not exactly what I want.  I want the command to evaluate the difference by `Trade_id` regardless of where the `Trade_id`s are in each file and provide that difference.

Comment: I've formatted your question so it (hopefully) more accurately reflects the file contents; I figured it was highly unlikely all your data was on one line.

Answer (score 1):

That is not what Compare-Object is for / does. It compares the whole file against the other looking for thing in one that this not in the other.

As for this...

> regardless of where the Trade_ids are in each file

This, translate in my mind as the files you have are unstructured data. Just a text file with a bunch of trade info, the is scattered throughout the file.

There is no way to make Compare-Object do what you are asking for. You are going to have to code for this yourself.

If your files are not organized nicely, aka that unstructured data thing, you are going to have to parse each one to organize the data before you write additional code to execute your analysis effort.

PowerShell deals with objects, you need to turn your file construct in such a way as to make what you are after and object the you / PowerShell can work with.

Think of how you would go about making your trade file in to Excel spreadsheets, then these can be read by PowerShell using Import-Csv and from there you can parse and analyze your Excel data. Meaning, stuff like you show above all need to be in one row per line per file. The data hast to be turned in to a table with the trade_id as a key value to pivot on / connect with.

You example only shows a piece of you data file, not a decent size chunk of the file so the we know what you are working with for real, vs speculation.